# How to assign ajax parameter which is returned from controller method to a string at the View in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone how can I assign a parameter which is returned from controller method to a string at the View ? Here is my controller:

```
public string corporate()
        {
            var management = "1";

            return (management);
        }
```

And my view:

```
@{
string parameter=""+ @:<div id="ajaxvalue"></div>;
}
```

But I can't assign the parameter how can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it to the view by using `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult corporate()
{
    ViewBag.management = "1";
    return PartialView();
}
```

and inside the corresponding view:

```
@ViewBag.management
```

or a better approach would be to define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Management { get; set; }
}
```

then have your controller action pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult corporate()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Management = "1";
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and finally have a strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Model.Management
```

Yet another possibility if you are calling this controller action with AJAX is to return JSON:

```
public ActionResult corporate()
{
    return Json(new { management = "1" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```